# Python как через параметры передать в запрос SQL функцию

Tags: python

необходимо через параметры передать SQL функцию values(date_update) в запрос, как это можно организовать ?
Добавление значений в массив

```
self.sub.append((
            float(price_parse),float(price_parse),"values(date_update)",int(url)
                ))
```

Сам запрос

```
quer="Update check_games set price=%s, last_price=%s, date_update=%s where id_url=%s"
```

Comment: опишите конкретнее

Comment: При подстановке параметра в запрос к полю date_update он подставляет так date_update="values(date_update)", а надо чтобы вставлял параметр без кавычек, т.е вот так date_update=values(date_update)